# Print Arabic (RTL) and English (LTR) in the correct directions at the same time

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, right-to-left, bidi

I want to output "Arabic" and "English" text at the same time in Java for example, outputting the following statement: `مرحبا I am Adham`.

I searched the internet and I found that the BiDi algorithm is needed in this case. Are there any java classes for BiDi.

I have tried this class [BiDiReferenceJava](http://www.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/BidiReferenceJava/) and I tested it, but when I call `runSample()` in the class `BidiReferenceTest` and entering an arabic string as parameter, I got an `OutOfIndexException` as the count of the character is duplicated (exactly at this line of code in the class `BidiReferenceTestCharmap`)

```
byte[] result = new byte[count];
```

Where if the string length is `4` the count is `8`!

Comment: What are you outputting to? What is the problem when you just print out the text?

Comment: Java UI components already know how to handle BiDi so in general you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

The ICU4J is more or less the standard comprehensive Unicode library for Java, and thus supports the bidirectional algorithm. I really wonder why you need this, though; BiDi is usually applied by the display layer, unless you're a word-processor or something.

BidiReference.java is apparently a demonstration piece; it's designed to show how the algorithm works on ASCII characters instead of using actual Unicode characters.

Comment: The ICU4J has Bidi classes for Java; it's an direct answer to the question "Are there any java classes for BiDi."